# Chrome is not rendering text when it is originally hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, render

My goal was to make a simple `Load More` button. I had my `container` div which contained a total of 20 components and I only wanted to show and load 5 at a time. I started by making the height of the `container` equal to the height of just 5 components with `overflow: hidden` to prevent the rest of the components from showing. Once the `Load More` button was pressed the height of the `container` was changed to the height of ten components thus showing 10 components; then it was changed to the height of 15 components and so on.

This worked perfectly in Firefox and Safari however when I tried to load more in Chrome, some of the text would not be rendered. Upon checking in the inspector it was clear to see that the text was in fact there, just not rendered.

[image: missing text]
When it should look like this:

[image: correct text]

This could be solved by focusing on a given component (e.g. highlighting the hidden text or hovering over a button within the component). However having users focus on a component to see what it says is not good practice.

I tried making all the components hidden and when the `Load More` button was pressed make those that were just loaded not hidden, to no avail. I also tried setting the innerHTML of each component to itself which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the solution that worked was setting a specific style of the `container`

`.component {-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);}`

I don't know why this worked so if anyone has an answer as to why this works, comment below.